# Find the minimum number of shots to be taken to ensure monkey is hit?

Tags: algorithm, graph

You are a hunter in a forest and would like to shoot a monkey on a group of connected trees. We can take one shot at a time. After every shot, monkey will jump to adjacent tree. It would need to change its position every time a shot is taken. What would be the minimum shots to be taken to make sure monkey gets shot? As an input, we got a list of trees which are adjacent to each other. For example: lets consider the below 3 graphs:

[image]

For the (i) graph: we can shoot in this order of nodes: `2 3 3 2`. We will get the monkey shot in this order for sure.

For the (ii) graph: (*if we remove node 10 from the graph*) the order would be: `2 3 4 5 6 7 7 6 5 4 3 2`.

For the (iii) graph: Solution is impossible.

Below is a brief overview of the algorithm I have implemented to come up with the solution:

1. Check if the cycle is presented in the given undirected graph. (We can do it by implementing DFS and keeping track of visited and parent node.)
2. If cycle exists, no solution is possible.
3. If cycle is absent, find the length of the longest path using DFS in this graph. Let `n` be the total number of nodes present in the longest path and let them be numbered as `1` to `n`.
4. If `n` is odd, shots must be fired in this order at these nodes:
   `2 n-1 n-2 n-3 ....2 n-1 n-2 n-3 ....2`
5. If `n` is even, the the order of shots is:
   `2 3 4.....n-2 n-1 n-1 n-2 .....4 3 2`

For example, if the number of nodes in the longest path is 5, then the shot order will be

`2 4 3 2 4 3 2`

if number of nodes is 8, then order will be

`2 3 4 5 6 7 7 6 5 4 3 2`

6. **Also find if there exists any node in the graph which is at a distance 2 or more than any of the nearest node present in the longest path. If there exists such node, then the solution is impossible to exist.**

Using the above algorithm, I can sort out most of the cases, but I actually have an issue with the 6th step. Is there anyway that my conclusion regarding 6th point is true, then there can't be any solution? In that case, how can I solve it? And do my current algorithm work fine for this problem efficiently or is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: I have doubt regarding algorithm for this problem. It will be very long if I put the whole code here. So I put the exact steps of my algorithm I came up with.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but I suspect the reason you got downvoted was because of this. Please look at how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Well this is the minimal, complete and verifiable algorithm that I have worked out at my end and I can verify that this works. Not sure why people are still downvoting it! :(

Comment: your solution for ii is false: the monkey can just stay switch between 9 and 10 all the time

Comment: @gdelab: Yes. This is one of those cases that comes under point 6 as I mentioned. Since node 10 is at a distance 2 from its nearest node in the longest path i.e. node 4, it is impossible for the solution to exist. If, however, we don't have node 10, then the solution would be the one I mentioned. I should have mentioned it. Thanks for pointing it. I have corrected it.

Comment: For a simple straight line of 5 node, the shortest solution is `2 3 4 4 3 2`

Comment: @hk6279: I believe it will be the one I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway that my conclusion regarding 6th point is true, then
>   there can't be any solution? In that case, how can I solve it?

Found a counter example for you 6th point

```
    z
    a
1-2-3-4-5
```

There exist a solution `a 3 2 3 4 a 3 2 3 4` for the example

1. {1 2 3 4 5 a z} < a> {1 2 3 4 5 z} => {1 2 3 4 5 a}
2. {1 2 3 4 5 a} <3> {1 2 4 5 a} => {1 2 3 4 5 z}
3. {1 2 3 4 5 z} <2> {1 3 4 5 z} => {2 3 4 5 a}
4. {2 3 4 5 a} <3> {2 4 5 a} => {1 3 4 5 z}
5. {1 3 4 5 z} <4> {1 3 5 z} => {2 4 a}
6. {2 4 a} < a> {2 4} => {1 3 5}
7. {1 3 5} <3> {1 5} => {2 4}
8. {2 4} <2> {4} => {3 5}
9. {3 5} <3> {5} => {4}
10. {4} <4> {}

{possible monkey position} < shooting position> {possible alive monkey position after shot} => {possible monkey position after move}

> And do my current algorithm work fine for this problem efficiently or
>   is there any better way to do this?

For type (i) graph [length of longest path = n and without cycle], return

1. n, when n<=2
2. 2n-4, when n>2

For n>2, you will found the solution is always `2 3 4 ... n-2 n-1 n-1 n-2 ... 4 3 2`. For example, a type (i) graph of length 5

```
1-2-3-4-5
```

1. {1 2 3 4 5} <2> {1 3 4 5} => {2 3 4 5}
2. {2 3 4 5} <3> {2 4 5} => {1 3 4 5}
3. {1 3 4 5} <4> {1 3 5} => {2 4}
4. {2 4} <4> {2} => {1 3}
5. {1 3} <3> {1} => {2}
6. {2} <2> {}

---

Further thinking of my solution, classify a graph into two type of nodes where all adjacent node are opposite node type of current node

```
A-B-A-B-A
```

The above solution is simply attempt to restrict monkey to stay in only one type of node at certain point, say node type A. Afterward, the monkey can only stay in either node type A or node type B. The remaining process is to eliminate remaining nodes of same types.

Comment: The above conclusions seem to match with what I worked on. But I guess you would need to separate out cases for odd and even number of nodes in the longest path. Anyways, I wanted to have solution for type 3 graphs where we have separate nodes apart from longest path of length n, that might form a second longest path of length n-1.

Comment: @ashishkumar For type 1 graph, odd number of node or even number of node makes no differ. You can always use n-2 shot to remove 1 type of node describe in last paragraph. and then use another n-2 shot to remove remaining possibility.

Comment: yeah, that's true. But for type 2 graph, it still becomes difficult to find a solution in case more longer paths of such kind exists. I just want to verify that.

Comment: @ashishkumar For type 2 graph, it might be better to use DP to let program to check if there is solution. It will be hard to figure out generic solution for type 2 graph.

Comment: That would be an interesting approach really. Thanks for pointing that out. Let me try on those lines and see if I end up somewhere meaningful.